# Qual a eficiência do operator spread quando copiando objetos JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Recentemente vi um comentário por aí que falava sobre a performance do operador "spread" ou "espalhamento" no JavaScript.

A questão essencialmente seria: se quisermos copiar um objeto e por qualquer razão não pudermos usar os métodos providos pelo JavaScript para fazer isso, como implementaríamos essa função.

Isso só faz sentido se os valores forem manipulados de alguma forma, como por exemplo, se a cópia tenha de ser profunda. Se esse não for o caso, **deveríamos simplesmente usar**:

```js
const copy = { ...object };
```

Ou:

```js
const copy = Object.assign({}, object);
```

---

Com isso, a confusão seria, entre as duas formas seguintes de se copiar um objeto, qual seria a mais eficiente:

```js
function copyObjectWithSpread(target) {
  const keys = Object.keys(target);

  return keys.reduce((memo, key) => ({
    ...memo,
    [key]: target[key]
  }), {});
}
```

Ou:

```js
function copyObjectWithAssignment(target) {
  const keys = Object.keys(target);

  return keys.reduce((memo, key) => {
    memo[key] = target[key];
    return memo;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: A pergunta parte de premissas equivocados. Os dois códigos da metade de cima não são equivalentes, embora façam coisas "parecidas". O primeiro faz cópia rasa, o segundo não exatamente. Já os dois de baixo também fazem cópias rasas, nenhum faz cópia profunda (isso só com recursão). A única diferença entre as duas funções é que o uso do spread é totalmente inútil na primeira. A comparação deveria ser spread sem reduce (como em `const copy = { ...object };)`, vs reduce sem spread.

Comment: Olá, @bfavaretto, eu concordo sim. O exemplo é uma cópia rasa e só ilustra o custo da cópia quadrática. Por isso menciono que a forma própria de escrever isso seria apenas com um spread ou assign.

O segundo tem exatamente a mesma saída que o primeiro ainda que seja menos eficiente.

Comment: * só é mais eficiente. O segundo é mais eficiente.. :D

Comment: Não entendi bem o seu argumento, o teste que eu faria é este: https://jsperf.com/shallow-copy-spread-vs-reduce

Comment: Sim, mas na discussão havia manipulação.

Comment: Seu exemplo é diferente. A questão é dada a possibilidade de manipulação qual a forma mais eficiente de copiar o objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso nós quiséssemos implementar uma boa função de cópia, é importante entender que na primeira versão:

```js
{ ...memo, [key]: target[key] }
```

Está copiando `memo` para esse novo objeto temporário em cada iteração e o jogando fora. Enquanto:

```
base[prop] = value
```

É só um assignment comum.

Como isso está em um loop no reduce, o resultado acumulado é copiado de novo e de novo em todas as iterações.

Na primeira iteração o acumulador tem 0 propriedades, então há um custo 0, mas nas seguintes há um custo:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n = n?
```

Onde `n` é o número de chaves.

Essa soma é como um "fatorial aditivo" e foi chamada de ["função termial"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termial) por Donald Knuth. Também pode ser escrita como a soma dos termos em uma progressão aritmética:

```
n? = ( n ^ 2 + n ) / 2
```

Assim a primeira versão tem complexidade **quadrática O(n^2)** em função do número de chaves. Enquanto a segunda tem complexidade **linear O(n)** em função do número de chaves.

Na prática, a cópia da primeira forma (spread no loop) sempre será mais lenta mesmo para um número pequeno de chaves e cada vez mais quanto mais chaves houverem.

Escrevi o seguinte script para testar os efeitos em meu próprio computador:

```js
let r;

const properlyTypedObjectWith8Keys = {
  key7: false,
  key1: "here",
  key2: "there",
  key3: "yey",
  key4: new String(),
  key5: 123,
  key6: /polymorphic/,
  key8: {}
};

const numKeys = 10e6;
const propertyValue = "stuff here";
const nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys = {};

for (let i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
  nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys[
    "random-key" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)
  ] = propertyValue;
}

function copyingMerge(o) {
  return function run(base, prop) {
    return { ...base, [prop]: o[prop] };
  };
}

function nonCopyingMerge(o) {
  return function run(base, prop) {
    base[prop] = o[prop];
    return base;
  };
}

function runMerge(object, merge) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(merge(object), {});
}

function assert(bool) {
  if (!bool) {
    throw new Error("assertion failed");
  }
}

function testCopyingMerge() {
  const result = runMerge(properlyTypedObjectWith8Keys, copyingMerge);

  const resultKeys = Object.keys(result);

  assert(resultKeys.length === 8);
  resultKeys.forEach(key => {
    assert(result[key] === properlyTypedObjectWith8Keys[key]);
  });
}

function testNonCopyingMerge() {
  const result = runMerge(properlyTypedObjectWith8Keys, nonCopyingMerge);

  const resultKeys = Object.keys(result);

  assert(resultKeys.length === 8);
  resultKeys.forEach(key => {
    assert(result[key] === properlyTypedObjectWith8Keys[key]);
  });
}

function testCopyingMergeWithUntyped() {
  const result = runMerge(nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys, copyingMerge);

  const resultKeys = Object.keys(result);

  assert(
    resultKeys.length === Object.keys(nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys).length
  );
  resultKeys.forEach(key => {
    assert(result[key] === nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys[key]);
  });
}

function testNonCopyingMergeWithUntyped() {
  const result = runMerge(nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys, nonCopyingMerge);

  const resultKeys = Object.keys(result);

  assert(
    resultKeys.length === Object.keys(nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys).length
  );
  resultKeys.forEach(key => {
    assert(result[key] === nonProperlyTypedObjectWith8Keys[key]);
  });
}

function runBenchmark(iterations, name, fn) {
  const start = Date.now();
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      fn();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(name, "failed", err.stack);
    throw err;
  }

  const end = Date.now();

  const el = document.querySelector('#' + name);
  el.innerText = [
    name,
    "levou",
    ((end - start) / iterations) + 'ms',
    "em média"
  ].join(' ');
}

runBenchmark(1e6, "copying-result", testCopyingMerge);
runBenchmark(1e6, "noncopying-result", testNonCopyingMerge);

// This is so slow that it can't run a million times.
runBenchmark(100, "copying-result-big", testCopyingMergeWithUntyped);
runBenchmark(100, "noncopying-result-big", testNonCopyingMergeWithUntyped);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Com operador spread, 8 chaves</h1>
<div id="copying-result"></div>

<h1>Sem operador spread, 8 chaves</h1>
<div id="noncopying-result"></div>

<h1>Com operador spread, 1 milhão de chaves</h1>
<div id="copying-result-big"></div>

<h1>Sem operador spread, 1 milhão de chaves</h1>
<div id="noncopying-result-big"></div>
```

Ele é executável no seu próprio navegador.

Com 8 chaves há uma diferença de ~5x. Com 10e6 chaves aqui há ~150x de diferença.

Se isso importa ou não para seu caso de uso de construção de objetos de maneira geral dependerá. **Normalmente não há tantos problemas em copiar objetos, mesmo milhões de copias devem ser razoavelmente baratas com poucas chaves.**

No entanto, no contexto de escrever uma função de cópia de boa qualidade, não parecem haver motivos para usar uma função quadrática ao invés de uma linear. Considerando que ambas são igualmente legíveis.

Comment: Você entendeu o motivo da saída do spread ter sido jogada fora em `copyObjectWithSpread`? O spread não faz nada ali e não faz sentido. A comparação deveria ser spread sem reduce (como em `const copy = { ...object };`), vs reduce sem spread. Os dois fazem cópias rasas.

Comment: Sim, aqui não há sentido em escrever a função de cópia, como eu menciono no 3º parágrafo da pergunta. E o ponto seria que em uma função de cópia de fato o spread não seria próprio dessa forma.

Estava tentando explicar para uma discussão. Essas são as alternativas apresentadas na discussão, o que mostra que não estava clara a complexidade da cópia.